# PHP pear not locating php executable

Tags: php, pear

PHP pear is not locating the correct php executable. When I type `pear config-show` It is showing the following error.

```
/usr/local/bin/pear: line 28: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.36/bin/php: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/pear: line 28: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.36/bin/php: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

But when I execute `which php` I am getting

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

How I should configure this in pear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the location of the php binary. You can do this with the following:

```
$ pear config-set php_bin /usr/local/bin/php
```

If that doesn't work, you could link the non-existant php to the correct one:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.36/bin/php
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: first option does not work because the pear is not functional.

Comment: I tried doing symlink and it helped, then I went doing first reconfiging option, it went with no error messages, however, when I deleted the symlink the pear stopped working, meaning the reconfiging is not working att all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with macPorts

Symlink fixed it

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/php56 /opt/local/bin/php
```